# Subtract a comma and a bracket from an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, parsing, arraylist

I am trying to build a scraper in java for fun. I feel like I have gotten most of the hard code down I just need to organize it now. I need to somehow subtract "[" "]" and a comma at the beginning of each line. I believe we are working with the parse_source_code function but I could be wrong. Help would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Scraper {
    public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception{

        String webURL = "https://statsroyale.com/clan/99VUU8Y";
        write_data(parse_source_code(get_url_source(webURL)));
}

    public static List<String> get_url_source(String URL)throws Exception {

        List <String> source = new ArrayList <>();

        URL webLink = new URL(URL);

        HttpsURLConnection statsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) webLink.openConnection();
        statsConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        statsConnection.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(statsConnection.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            source.add(inputLine);
            in.close();

        return source;
  }
    public static List<String> parse_source_code(List<String> source_code) {

        List <String> data = new ArrayList <>();

        List <String> rank = new ArrayList <>();
        List <String> name = new ArrayList <>();
        List <String> level = new ArrayList <>();
        List <String> league = new ArrayList <>();  
        List <String> trophies = new ArrayList <>();
        List <String> donations = new ArrayList <>();
        List <String> role = new ArrayList <>();

        for (int i = 0; i < source_code.size(); i++) {
            if (source_code.get(i).contains("<div class=\"clan__rowContainer\">")) {
                String Prank = source_code.get(i + 2).split("                            ")[1];
                rank.add(Prank);
            }
            if (source_code.get(i).contains("/profile/")) { 
            String PName = source_code.get(i).split("'>")[1].split("</a")[0];
            name.add(PName);
            }
            if (source_code.get(i).contains("clan__playerLevel\">")) {  
                String Plevel = source_code.get(i).split("Level\">")[1].split("</span")[0];
                level.add(Plevel);
            }
            if (source_code.get(i).contains("<div class=\"league__")) { 
                String Pleague = source_code.get(i).split("\"league__")[1].split("\"></div>")[0];
                league.add(Pleague);
            }
            if (source_code.get(i).contains("class=\"clan__cup\">")) {  
                String Ptrophies = source_code.get(i).split("cup\">")[1].split("</div>")[0];
                trophies.add(Ptrophies);
            }
            if (source_code.get(i).contains("<div class=\"clan__cup\">")) { 
                String Pdonations = source_code.get(i + 2).split("row\">")[1].split("</div>")[0];
                donations.add(Pdonations);
            }
            if (source_code.get(i).contains("<div class=\"clan__cup\">")) { 
                String Prole = source_code.get(i + 4).split("             ")[1];
                role.add(Prole);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < rank.size(); i++) {
            data.add(rank.get(i));
            data.add(name.get(i));
            data.add(level.get(i));
            data.add(league.get(i));
            data.add(trophies.get(i));
            data.add(donations.get(i));     
            data.add(role.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println(data);
        return data;
    }       
    public static void write_data(List <String> data)throws IOException {

        File csv = new File("CR CSV.TXT");

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter (csv);
            output.println(data);
            output.close();

    }
}
```

Again sorry if it is spaced wrong. Still trying to learn it. (Not as easy as it seems)

Comment: Is there some error you want help with?

Comment: No, it runs fine. But I just need to subtract the comma at the beginning of each line and then the brackets at the start and finish

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: whatever is in data

Comment: When you do that line where you expect it to print data, it just prints the reference to that array. You need to write a method that prints out the array

Comment: The print statement is just for testing in the end code I just want it to write to a csv.

Comment: Okay, well, you need to write the method for printing out the array. We won't help you code it, but we will help you with errors you have in it

Comment: @rabbitguy `data` is a List, not an array. Printing it doesn't just print a reference. And there's already a built-in method for printing an array: `Arrays.toString`.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder it's a reference regardless. Lists, btw, are arrays in memory :/

Comment: @rabbitguy Are you talking about something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@1a2b3c4d`? That happens because arrays don't override `Object.toString`. ArrayList won't print that, it will print the data it contains.

Comment: Also, only `ArrayList`s are necessarily arrays in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If these items go together I think this is a poor design:

```
    List <String> data = new ArrayList <>();

    List <String> rank = new ArrayList <>();
    List <String> name = new ArrayList <>();
    List <String> level = new ArrayList <>();
    List <String> league = new ArrayList <>();  
    List <String> trophies = new ArrayList <>();
    List <String> donations = new ArrayList <>();
    List <String> role = new ArrayList <>();
```

A better one would encapsulate all those things that go together into one object and have a single list of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a 3rd party library like [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to help with the HTML parsing, but if you want to do your own parsing and

> subtract "[" "]" and a comma at the beginning of each line

where each "line" is a `String`, I'd recommend using Java's `String.charAt()`, `String.substring()`, or even `String.replaceFirst()` methods.

The code would look something like

`if(line.charAt(0) == '[') {
      line = line.substring(1); 
}`

`if(line.charAt(0) == ']') {
      line = line.substring(1); 
}`

`if(line.charAt(0) == ',') {
      line = line.substring(1); 
}`

or even

`line = line.replaceFirst("[],");`

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do it but with what you have this will work:

Replace  output.println(data) with:

```
for(String token: data) {
            output.print(token);
            if(token.indexOf("\n") == -1) {
                output.print(", ");
            }
}
```

The [] and commas are comming from the toString of the ArrayList data, you have to print each element how you want rather than let toString do it for you.

My example is using the presence of a eol character to terminate the line, it would be better to store it in a Class with a clean toString method.